# Android HttpResponse not generic

Tags: java, android, httpresponse

I am getting the error: `The type HttpResponse is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <JsonNode>`

In normal Java it works but in Android its not?

```
     try 
        {  
           HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.post("http://example.com/example.php")
             .field("sender", sender)
             .field("body", body)

             .asJson();
              System.out.println(jsonResponse.getBody().toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

**imports:**

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Comment: can you post your imports on this class? and also check the android build target.

Comment: I have added the imports, what should I check for? thanks

Comment: May be this can help you : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html OR this one also : http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html

Comment: imports seems to be fine. From Build Path, Add Libraries and add the JRE System Library and also check android build target. It may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;`